# How to set corner with java code in Android

Tags: android

It is easy to set in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#BFEEFF" 
        android:endColor="#40B9FF" 
        android:angle="270"/>
    <corners 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dip"/>
</shape>
```

But how can I set it in java code?

Answer (score 1):

After inflation it's not a shape drawable (i know this is confusing),
  instead it's a GradientDrawable, the code is pretty straight forward check the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html
especially setCornerRadius().

```
GradientDrawable mDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
mDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
mDrawable.setCornerRadius(5.0f);
....
// (note, this is untested and you might need to set other properties,
// e.g. color etc.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create someView at Dynamic time . ( if this is true )

i know , its not a correct answer relative to your question , but i will give you a alternative way to perform this thing at dynamic time , add shape file inside Selector file and add selector file in View's android:drawable ="@drawable/selector" .